# Pick random values from a second table based on join in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, random

Suppose I have a Python dataframe:

```
A
B
C
A
B
```

...and a second dataframe

```
A  3
A  2
A  4
B  5
B  2
B  8
B  7
C  1
C  5
```

I want to join the second dataframe to the first - but for each value in the first frame, the join should be a random selection from the second row of the second dataframe picking only from where the first column is the same value.

So, for example, for the first value A in the first dataframe, I'd look in the second table and it would pick randomly from the values in the 2nd row whose first row value is an A - i.e. randomly select one of 3, 2 or 4. For the second value B, I'd pick randomly from 5,2,8 or 7. The end result I'd simply want a dataframe like:

```
A  2
B  8
C  1
B  7
A  4
```

Comment: does the result need to be in exactly the same order A B C B A?

Comment: Thank you for asking the question with sufficient explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say this is what you're starting with:

```
df1

  label
0     A
1     B
2     C
3     A
4     B

df2

  label  value
0     C      5
1     B      8
2     C      1
3     B      2
4     A      3
5     A      4
6     B      5
7     A      2
8     B      7
```

**Option 1: Merge on cumcounted key**
One easy way to do this is to shuffle `df2`, add an incremental key to both dataFrames and then merge:

```
df3 = df1.assign(key=df1.groupby('label').cumcount())
df4 = (df2.sample(frac=1)
          .reset_index(drop=True)
          .assign(key=lambda d: d.groupby('label').cumcount()))

df3.merge(df4, how='left', on=['label', 'key']).drop('key', 1)

  label  value
0     A      2
1     B      5
2     C      1
3     A      3
4     B      8
```

note: set `np.random.seed` for deterministic shuffles

---

**Option 2: Sample groups and concat**
Another option is to groupby df2, sample groups and concat

```
counts = df1['label'].value_counts() 
pd.concat([g.sample(n=counts[k]) for k, g in df2.groupby('label')])

  label  value
7     A      2
5     A      4
3     B      2
6     B      5
2     C      1
```

caveat here is that ordering isn't preserved.

Comment: `pd.Series` acts as a dict, so you don't need to use `to_dict()`.

Comment: Thanks for this - Option 1 worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that selects a random value from the second data frame and then use `df.apply` in the first data frame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'letter': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'letter': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
         'number': [3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 8, 7, 1, 5]})


def random_selection(letter):
    choices = df2.loc[df2['letter'].eq(letter), 'number']
    return np.random.choice(choices)

df1['new_col'] = df1['letter'].apply(random_selection)
```